# Initialize Android custom component

Tags: android, android-edittext, initialization, components, extends

I have a extended EditText and I can not call any standard function with the following situation:

**MainActivity**

```
    private Editor sEditor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ex);

        sEditor = (Editor)findViewById(R.id.s_editor);
    }

    private String retText() {
        return sEditor.getText.toString();
    }
```

**Editor**

```
    public Editor(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public Editor(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public Editor(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
                     int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {

    }
```

When retText() is called:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable com.paulo.ex.Editor.getText()' on a null object reference
```

I also tried to initialize Editor as `sEditor = new Editor(MainActivity.this);` but the return value of retText() is always null. What is the appropriate way to resolve this problem?

Comment: "When retText() is called..." -- apparently `R.layout.activity_ex` does not have a widget named `s_editor`. "I also tried to initialize Editor as sEditor = new Editor(MainActivity.this); but the return value is always null." -- I guarantee that a constructor will not return `null`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Sorry, I expressed wrong, the constructor does not return null, but the getText yes!